# Calculating age in conditional split transformation

Tags: ssis

I've a requirement to split a table contents based on the age and I've a column DOB which is in string format and is of type '19910930'.I've used the following command and it works fine when run

```
DATEDIFF( YY,CONVERT(date,[DOB]),CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

and the same gives an error when I try it as condition in Conditional Split transformation as

```
DATEDIFF( YY,CONVERT(date,[DOB]),CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))<=25
```

I even tried a Derived Column transformation with the same expression and that too ain't working.

Could you please help me as where I'm missing out in this?

--Vijay

Comment: What do you mean gives error? Please add the error details in your question.

Comment: sreepat...I dont suppose it gives out a error message in conditional split transformation...all it shows is red colour which suggests that there's an error...Sorry for not being able to provide you the error message buddy..

Comment: be aware that `DateDiff(YY,,)` will not give you correct age for all dates. It ignores the month and day.

Answer (score 0):

try converting in this way:
DATEDIFF("YY",(DT_DATE)( SUBSTRING(@[User::DOB] ,1,4)+"-"+SUBSTRING (@[User::DOB] ,5,2)+"-"+SUBSTRING (@[User::DOB] ,7,2)) ,GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

DateDiff by year will not work when the day is between the first of the year and the [DOB]. As long as your [DOB] is in form YYYYMMDD. You can use this formula to get the age...

```
select
    CurrentAge = ((convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) - cast([DOB] as int)) / 10000)
```

the same formula in an SSIS expression would be very clunky with a bunch of DatePart calls to format the current date [System::ContainerStartTime] into the YYYYMMDD form and a conversion of [DOB] into DT_I4. I'd advise to do the calulation in the SQL select if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jayvee and dotjoe...I couldn't get it done either way But I instead used your suggestion to calculate age as a new column in the SQL itself while generating Source and could get the required result using condition split.

```
DATEDIFF(YY,CONVERT(DATE,DOB),CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) as Age
```

I hope there should be a way this can be done in Derived Column though..

Vjai

Comment: I tested the solution I proposed in a derived column and it did work. What was the issue when you tried on your application?